# Laravel where to put code that can be accessed from anywhere?

Tags: php, laravel

I currently have the following in a controller, it gets a user's avatar from S3, and if they have an avatar return the S3 url otherwise return the default.

```
public function GetAvatar(Request $request){
    $userid = Auth::user() ? Auth::user()->id : 0;
    $url = url('/cdn/avatar/default.png');
    if($userid > 0){
        $md5    = md5($userid);
        $disk   = Storage::disk('s3');
        $exists = $disk->has('avatars/' . $md5 . '.png');
        if($exists){
            $url = env('URL_AVATARS') . $md5 . '.png';
        }
    }
    return response()->json($url);
}
```

I don't want to have write this every time, so I want to move it to a centralized location so I can call it from anywhere. As I am still new to Laravel, I am not sure where I would put the code.

Do I make a `Service Provider`? `Middleware`? Something else? How would I then access this new method?

Comment: Hello you can create trait and include anywhere

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Defining content outside the controller?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34678736/defining-content-outside-the-controller)

Comment: Why not just make it an accessor on the user model? So you can do `$user->avatar` anywhere?

Comment: Aren't models made to interact with databases?

Comment: I think of a service/factory like in `Angular`. I can create an object and register it, then inject it into Controllers, and then modify it from anywhere that uses it and it will change everywhere. Basically it only gets instantiated once, so where ever it is used the values are all the same.

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn It's entirely fine to have parts of a model that don't come directly from the database using accessors. In fact, the documentation specifically highlights this. https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-serialization#appending-values-to-json "Occasionally, you may need to add array attributes that **do not have a corresponding column in your database**. To do so, first define an accessor for the value:"

Answer (score 3):

Just create a helper file in the apps folder.

```
<?php
//helper.php

function makeAvatar()
{
  // Your avatar function
  // return avatar
}
```

Now you can call this function from anywhere in your application as long as you auto-load the file.

To do that, go to your `composer.json` file and add the following

```
"autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database",
        ],
        "files":[
            "app/helper.php"  // Add this section
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
        }
    },
```

Just focus only on the files section.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you simply just make a Trait ? something like :

```
trait CanGetAvatar {
   public function GetAvatar(Request $request){
       ...
   }
}
```

then if you want all your controllers to use this trait simply append the main controller :

```
// in app/Http/Controllers/Controller.php
class Controller extends BaseController
{
    use AuthorizesRequests, DispatchesJobs, ValidatesRequests, CanGetAvatar;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class User extends Model {


    public function getAvatarAttribute(){
        $url = url('/cdn/avatar/default.png');
        $md5    = md5($this->id);
        $disk   = Storage::disk('s3');
        $exists = $disk->has('avatars/' . $md5 . '.png');
        if($exists){
            $url = env('URL_AVATARS') . $md5 . '.png';
        }
        return $url;
    }
}
```

Then you can just do `$user->avatar` to get the users avatar.

You can even add `public $appends = ['avatar']` to the top of the class, and your User model will always have an avatar attribute even when it is converted to json.

Comment: Change `$this->id` to  `$this->attributes['id']`

Comment: @JilsonThomas why would I do that?

Comment: I think last time I tried `$this->id`, it didn't work. I had to do `$this->attributes['id']` for some reason.

Comment: Anyway, just a suggestion if `$this->id` didn't work. :)

Comment: All attributes from the database as well as any you've created with a `getFooAttribute()` function are available as properties on the object

Comment: An accessor will override a property if they have same name.

Answer (score 1):

In your specific case, you definitely should use an `accessor` in the model.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators

When you need multiple `accessors`, you'll have to migrate them to a `presenter`.

The answer to the exact title of your question would be using `config` or `session` global helpers in a service provider. That would make their values available in controllers, models, views, presenters, observers, middlewares, etc.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/helpers#method-config

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/helpers#method-session